# checked no matter if value="" (is empty) in array of input checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, input, checkbox

Yup. This one is tearing me up. I found a lot of tutorials on this specific subject, but nothing seems to be working for me. I must be missing something which I cannot find.

I am simply trying to keep selected checkboxes checked if there is a previous error in the form. My validation is working totally fine with all fields, but I need to retain the checked boxes and I just can't solve this.

Here are the snippets I am working with:

*This checks if the $data[id] isset()*

```
<input name="seminar[]" type="checkbox" id="seminar[]" 
value="
<?php
if(isset($data['id'])) {
         $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
      } else {

        echo "";
      }
?>
" <?php echo "$checked"; ?>>
```

And I even checked in my html source, and this is what is showing after submission:

```
<input name="seminar[]" type="checkbox" id="seminar[]" value="" checked="checked">
```

As you can see value="" is empty!, so in my script above it should echo "", but that's not working.

As a matter of fact, when I clear the cache and reload the form all boxes are just checked!?

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong. Maybe I am turning over the wrong stones here.. Dunno, but nearly 4 hours down the drain and I'm waiving a white flag.

Comment: php code is not showing. I guess its a moderated thing here : )

Comment: You need to select the PHP and click the {} button to make it show properly.

Comment: I just fixed it up. In order for code to show up, you need to just indent it by four spaces.

Comment: @OldWest: I hope it is fixed now and didn't omit anything. crimson_penguin is right on how to format it.

Comment: Sorry, what? PHP is doing things right. What do you expect PHP to output? Based on the output, $data['id'] is set and then value will be outputted "" and it will be checked.

Comment: I did use the code insert {}, and it still displayed incorrect. I received a personal message from a moderator saying the code was corrected earlier.

Comment: VoodooChild, I tried using the 4 spaces instead of the {} WYSIWYG button and seems fine now, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several things wrong that could possibly be contributing to your problem.

First, you're assigned the `name` of the checkbox `seminar[]`. This creates an array with values from all checkboxes that use that name. Since you're not specifying a key in between the `[]`, it automatically does this for you. You should specify some sort of key yourself so you can match them up later.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seminar[0]" id="seminar_0" value="" />
```

Then you can check if it's set by doing this:

```
if(isset($_POST['seminiar'][0])) {
  echo "checked=\"checked\"";
}
```

Second, you can't use `seminar[]` for the `ID` of the checkbox. Look at my above example for an alternative way you can do it. IDs have to be unique on the page; You cannot use the same ID twice on a single page.

Third, what is this `$data['id']` exactly? You should be checking the `$_POST` value for the exact name of the item. Again, look at my first example.

I'd reformat your code to look something like this:

```
$checkboxes = array(0 => "Value 1", 1 => "Value 2", 2 => "Value 3");
foreach($checkboxes as $k => $v) {
  echo '<label for="seminar_'.$k.'">'.$v.'</label><input type="checkbox" name="seminar['.$k.']" id="seminar_'.$k.'" value="'.htmlentities($v).'" '.(isset($_POST['seminar'][$k]) ? 'checked="checked" ' : '').'/>';
}
```

Comment: Michael, your comment was very helpful : ). This is what I did, and it's all working now:  <?php if(isset($_POST['seminar']["$a"])) {
  $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; } else {
  $checked = "";
}
 ?>

<input name="seminar[<?php echo $a; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="seminar_<?php echo $a; ?>"
value="" <?php echo $checked; ?>>. , but when I am trying to insert into my table using (existing code) this no longer works:  if($seminar)
  { 
  foreach ($seminar as $s )
  $interest .= "$s ";
   }. any idea how I can process this new array structure based on a foreach()?

Comment: Glad I can help. One thing, you don't need double quotes around `$a` in `isset($_POST['seminar']["$a"])`. Just do `isset($_POST['seminar'][$a])`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the added tip :-) .. I am going to create a new thread to my other question as it's somewhat a different topic.